# Looking for Oauth Yahoo sample C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, dotnetopenauth, yahoo

I know threre a lot of libraries dotnetopenauth,oauthbase, etc.
But i need sample of using with yahoo. 
Samples,which i find did not work for me.Maybe you have example.Please share :-)
I find bug OauthBase work fine for me :-)

Comment: Check this post http://www.matlus.com/oauth-c-library/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This 
[one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Delicious-OAuth-API.aspx), I found explained very well. And this [one](http://oauth.net/code/) is from oAuth official site

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is [SocialAuth.NET](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-net/)

This library takes care of all token generation and handshake with Yahoo, Google, Facebook and MSN and expose methods like Login(), GetProfile() and GetContacts(). Infact it also provides option to use its inbuilt authentication engine using which a site with no authentication can be turned authentication enabled with these providers in less than 10 minutes.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a bit out dated and poorly documented. I've spent days trying to get either the sample to work or to integrate it with a MVC 4 site and it's been non stop frustration.

Comment: SocialAuth.NET has a MVC3 working demo within its package. I've tried the demo in VS2012 as well. Though SocialAuth.NET framework is primarily meant to work with webforms, but it does work with MVC provided <code>routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allaspx}", new { allaspx = @".*\.sauth(/.*)?" }); </code> is added in global.asax. However, an MVC integrated variant of socialauth.net is in its way of development. Its recently upgraded to support Google and LinkedIn OAuth 2.0.